# How to use strcmp to compar names in a csv Data

Tags: c, csv, strcmp

i want to open a csv file and compare the contents of the first row.
I have the code to open the file already written, i only do not know how I can compare the first line with strcmp from the open file.

To open the file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

   int main(void) {
         setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
         setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

          FILE *f;
          char file_name[255];
          char data[127];

          printf("Which file you want to open : ");
          scanf("%s",file_name);

          f = fopen("C:\\projekt\\datei.csv","r");
          if(f == NULL){
              printf("Could not open %s\n" ,file_name);
              exit(0);
          }

while( fgets(data, sizeof(data), f) != 0 )
    fputs(data, stdout);

    return 0;
```

}

Whats in the File

```
"Date"  "Time"  "Volt"  "Amp"   "Wirkfaktor"
26.10.13    08:00:00    237.802 1160.7682   0.7461853792
26.10.13    08:00:01    237.658 1168.92273  0.7203561543
26.10.13    08:00:02    237.815 1158.57273  0.7344799394
26.10.13    08:00:03    237.566 1174.5682   0.6960312563
26.10.13    08:00:04    238.063 1151.67273  0.80126914



  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>


 int main(void) {
 setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
 setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

FILE *f;
char file_name[255];
char data[127];

printf("Which file you want to open : ");
scanf("%s",file_name);

f = fopen("C:\\projekt\\datei.csv","r");
if(f == NULL){
    printf("Could not open %s\n" ,file_name);
    exit(0);
}

 while( fgets(data, sizeof(data), f) != NULL ){
      //fputs(data, stdout);

}

int good = 1;
int i;

char heading[5][20];
if ( sscanf( data, "%19s%19s%19s%19s%19s", heading[0], heading[1], heading[2], heading[3], heading[4] ) != 5 )
{
    good = 0;
}

if ( good )
{

    char *expected[5] = { "\"Date\"t\"Time\"t\"Volt\"t\"Amp\"t\"Wirkfaktor\"" };
    for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
        if ( strcmp( expected[i], heading[i] ) != 0 )
            good = 0;
}

if ( !good )
{
    printf( "Heading line is incorrect\n" );
    exit( 0 );
}


 return 0;


}
```

Comment: `fgets(data, sizeof(data), f) != 0` -> `fgets(data, sizeof(data), f) != NULL`

Comment: thank you, although it also works with 0

Comment: To what exactly do you want to compare the first line of the file? And what do you mean by first line? The header line or the first data line? And what should be the result of your comparison?

Comment: Yes, because in your case `NULL` is defined as `0` or `(void *)0`, but you can not rely on this in all implementations, why are you (f)opening a fixed path after requesting a path?

Comment: @honk 13 If "Date", "Time", "Volt" "Amp"  "Wirkfaktor" is not in the first line of the file is the file incorrectly. If the file contains "Date", "Time", "Volt" "Amp"  "Wirkfaktor" in the first line, the file is correct

Comment: @ Alter Mann I tried to open the file automatically, but I decided for the manual version.

Comment: Note: you should not be calling `setvbuf`, unless you have a very good reason to do so. This code has absolutely no reason to call `setvbuf`.

Comment: @Alter Mann Code _can_ rely on this in all implementations.  All null pointers including `NULL`, compare equally equate to `0`.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far guys, but I do not know how I can recognize from the csv file if I have a tap or spacebar.

Comment: `sscanf` will work with tabs or spaces.

Answer (score 0):

To verify that the first line of the file is correct, first extract the five strings using `sscanf`, and then compare the strings with the expected strings, using `strcmp`.

```
int good = 1;

char heading[5][20];
if ( sscanf( data, "%19s%19s%19s%19s%19s", heading[0], heading[1], heading[2], heading[3], heading[4] ) != 5 )
    good = 0;

if ( good )
{
    char *expected[5] = { "\"Date\"", "\"Time\"", "\"Volt\"", "\"Amp\"", "\"Wirkfaktor\"" };
    for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
        if ( strcmp( expected[i], heading[i] ) != 0 )
            good = 0;
}

if ( !good )
{
    printf( "Heading line is incorrect\n" );
    exit( 1 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are simply trying to see if it contains those 5 strings, perhaps consider using `strtok` to split the first line into tokens, and then compare those tokens to the strings you want it to contain using `strcmp`. The code for this is listed below.
2. If you are trying to get that specific string, than your string to compare the first line to would be `"\"Date\"\t\"Time\"\t\"Volt\"\t\"Amp\"\t\"Wirkfaktor\""` assuming that the first line is tab separated.

```
char* result = NULL;
char delims[] = {'"', ' '}; // split on spaces and double quotes
char check[] = {"Date","Time","Volt","Amp","Wirkfaktor"};
result = (char*)strtok( data, delims );
int i = 0;
while(result != NULL) {
    if(strcmp(result,check[i]) {
        printf("File Invalid\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    result = (char*)strtok( NULL, delims);
    i++;
}
// If we get here than the file was good.
```

Comment: Regarding your second point: Please be careful. I guess the file is tab-separated, because it is a csv file, but doesn't contain commas.   Therefore comparison would be needed to be done against: `"\"Date\"\t\"Time\"\t\"Volt\"\t\"Amp\"\t\"Wirkfaktor\""`.

Comment: Thanks, I added an update to reflect the tab separated string

Comment: Ok, maybe you should also add that you now assume a tab-separated file. By the way, are you sure your code is correct? There is a missing `}` in the third line and I think that you have to call `strtok` several times until you processed all tokens. Now you seem to only compare the first string (`"Date"`) of the file to the `check` array. As `result` isn't changed in the loop, it seems to be an infinite loop...

Comment: ugh, thanks for saving me again. Added missing closing bracket, and linked in the updated strtok in the while, which fixes the infinite loop and compares the rest.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


FILE *f;
char file_name[255];
char data[127];

char dataRef[]="26.10.13    08:00:00    237.802 1160.7682   0.7461853792";

main() 
{
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);



    f = fopen("datei.csv","r");
    if(f == NULL){
        printf("Could not open %s\n" ,file_name);
        exit(0);
    }

    while( fgets(data, sizeof(data), f) != 0 )
    {
    fputs(data, stdout);
    if (strncmp(dataRef,data,56)==0)
    {
    printf(" Here's the tip's between the file chain and the stack reference chain ....");
    fputs(data, stdout);
    fputs(dataRef, stdout);
    printf("\n");
    }}}
```

Note: In the new code i have deplaced the auto declarations out of the main corps, cause of my vc6 compilo who are in disgrace with this in-main  declarations.
I wrote a short solution with ,i suppose, your imagination. It doesn't matter you can certainly unterstand the use of strcmp or strncmp who's the same function with the formating property. See you later.

Comment: If you take a look at the comment on the question, you will see that the OP is talking about the header line in the file and not about the first data line.

Comment: Also read the comments below the answer from BryanS. It's likely that the lines contain tab characters, so the comparison you propose won't work.

Comment: to user3386109.  Yes no really take a good look but why dont you want that the comparaison dont work ? please.  Try the code it run right ... thanks. Tab is just a possible separator for scanf